# How do I write a regex for a string like this - (abcd)-123456-abc-123

Tags: .net, regex, c#-3.0

Please help me to write a regular expression to capture following format,

**Eg: (abcd)-123456-abc-123**

```
<open parenthesis><4 characters><close parenthesis><hyphen ><6 digits><hyphen><3-characters><hyphen><3 digits>
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is the problem you faced while writing the regex :)

Comment: Maybe this tool could help you a lot: http://www.regexr.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This *might* work, depending on what you're situation is.

```
\([A-Za-z]{4}\)-[0-9]{6}-[A-Za-z]{3}-[0-9]{3}
```

If you want to learn more about regular expressions in C#, there's a [Quick Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc(v=vs.110).aspx).

In the future, please provide as much information about your problem, what you have tried, and what you're trying to accomplish. It will help get you the answer you're looking for faster and potentially help future programmers determine whether your question and accepted answer apply to them.

There's even a friendly reminder on the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) page:

> *Provide details. Share your research.*

Answer (score 2):

This is the match pattern:

```
(?<=<open parenthesis>)([a-zA-Z]{4})(<close parenthesis><hyphen >)([0-9]{6})(<hyphen>)([a-zA-Z]{3})([0-9]{3})
```

And this the replace pattern

```
$1-$3-$5-$6
```

Info: I tested this with RegexBuddy with ".NET" selected! Depending on what you use you may have to change something!

Answer (score -1):

The regexp
(....)-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[a-b][a-b][a-b]-[0-9][0-9][0-9]
matches your example above. There is an inconsistency between your example and our criteria. Following your criteria 
(....)-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[a-b][a-b][a-b][0-9][0-9][0-9]
is the correct regexp.